# Previous selected date doesn't get unselected in calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I only want to have one selected date on my calendar UI, however when I press a new date, the old one is still lit up, and so I can press all the days on my calendar and they'll all light up.

```
for(var dayCounter = 1; dayCounter <= currMonthDays; dayCounter++){

    tempListItem = document.createElement("li");
    tempListItem.innerHTML = dayCounter;
    $(tempListItem).addClass("day");
    //add a hidden element to the day that we can access when we click on it
    var temp = months[currMonth] +"/" + dayCounter +"/" + currFullYear;
    $(tempListItem).append("<div class = 'hidden'>" + temp + "</div>");

    if(dayCounter == date.getDate() && currMonth == date.getMonth()){
        tempListItem.setAttribute("id", "current-day");
    }

    ulDays.appendChild(tempListItem);
}
$(document).on("click", ".day", function()
{
    var date = $(this).children(".hidden").text();
    console.log(date);
    $(document.getElementById("current-day")).removeAttr("#current-day");
    $(this).attr("id", "current-day");
});
```

After removing the current-day class, shouldn't the element lose its CSS?

Comment: provide your html

Comment: You’re adding the ID as an attribute. It looks like you’d be better off using classes for this. You can then remove the class instead of removing the ID which doesn’t sound like a good idea...

Comment: @patrick I still get the same problem after changing it to a class :(

Comment: I don't think that's how removeAttr() works anyway - that would look for an attribute called #current-day (which is invalid), not one containing it. If you switch to classes, use removeClass() instead of removeAttr().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a small big when you try to remove the `id` from the `current-day`. `removeAttr` expects the name of an attribute. In this case, that attribute would be `id`, so try this:

```
$(document.getElementById("current-day")).removeAttr("id");
```

Comment: Although this might work, it doesn’t seem like a smart thing to make ID’s dynamic like this. That’s not the way to go. This is what classes are for. So for the love of whoever, I hope people don’t choose this accepted answer as the solution when they encounter the same error!!